# Deleting rows in datastore by time range

Tags: sql, postgresql, ckan

I have a CKAN datastore with a column named "recvTime" of type timestamp (i.e. using "timestamp" as type at datastore_create time, [as shown in this link](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/blob/develop/resources/ckan-scripts/create_datastore.sh)). Example value for this column is "2014-06-12T16:08:39.542000".

I have a large numbers of records in the datastore (thousands) and I would like to delete the rows before a given date in "recvTime". My first thought was doing it using the REST API with the datastore_delete operation using a range filter, but it is not possible as described [in the following Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206728/filtering-by-ranges-in-datastore-api).

Is there any other way of solving the issue, please?

Given that I have access to the host where CKAN server is running, I wonder if this could be achieved executing a regular SQL sentence on the Postgresql engine where the datastore is persisted. However, I haven't found information about manipulating the CKAN underlying datamodel in the CKAN documentation, so don't know if this a good idea or if it is risky...

Any workaround or information pointer is highly welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely do this directly on the underlying database if you were willing to dig in there (the structure is pretty simple with tables named after the corresponding resource id). You could even turn this into an API of your own using an extension (though you'd want to be careful about permissions).

You might also be interested in the new support (master only atm) for extending the DataStore API via a plugin in an extension - see https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/1725

Comment: Is there any piece of documentation in CKAN site about how to dig in the underlaying database, please? E.g. which parameters set for -U and -d (user and database) in the psql command.

Comment: Answering myself :)... `sudo -i -u postgres psql -d datastore_default` does the trick